# How to calculate Power Factor capacitors for welder

Tags: power, factor, reactive

I have a 200 Amp AC welder and I am trying to figure out what the power factor correction capacitor should be.  I ran some numbers but they do not sound right and I was wondering if I anybody could comment.

The manual says that if supplied with 230 VAC, 60 Hz power, at 200 amps output, the input current “with PF Capacitors” will be 46 amps and “without PF Capacitors” will be 68 amps.  The drawing shows an optional capacitor bank in parallel with the line.

If with PF correction, it draws 46 amps, I’ll assume that would be the real component of the uncorrected complex current.  If the absolute value of the current is 68 amps and real component is 46, that would give an imaginary current component of:

```
Im(I)=68*sin(arccos(46/68))
Im(I)=50 amps
```

The complex current would then be (46+50j).

As I recall, Ohm’s Law can be used with complex current and impedances:

```
V=I'Z' (where ' denotes complex values)
230=(46+50j)Z'
```

Solving for Z', this gives:

```
Z'=(2.29-2.49j) ohms
```

To correct for this lagging impedance, we need to put a capacitor in parallel with this with the resulting impedance being a (mostly) real value of 5 ohms.

Parallel impedances can be calculated with the formula:

Z= 1/(1/Z<sub>1</sub> + 1/Z<sub>2</sub>)

Substituting,

5=$\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{(2.29-2.49j)})}$
Solving for Z<sub>1</sub>(with more digits than I am showing), we get :

Z<sub>1</sub>=4.59j ohms

From this, we can find the required capacitance with

4.59j=${\frac{1}{j2\pi(60)C}}$
Solving for C, gives:

```
C=0.000577 farads
```

or

```
C=577 uF
```

That is a nice number but when I look on-line, the values I see are more like 50 uF.  Meanwhile, there is a 30 MFD in the output "Stabilizer Circuit" so maybe the people online have them conflated.

I can buy a 100 MFD capacitor, a bit smaller than a beer can, for about $20 but a vendor supplied power factor correction capacitor bank (with no units listed), costs several hundred dollars and looks to be the size of a shoebox so I'm not sure what to think.

Does anybody have any good ideas? Are my calculations correct and do they make sense?

The welder is a Lincoln Idealarc 250 AC. The drawing inside is dated 1961.  The vendor does not supply parts for something this old.

Comment: Contact a company that makes PF correction units - they will size this correctly. As you will need a control circuit to switch in and switch out the capacitors as the load varies.

Comment: @SolarMike, 1. I could ask but what fun is that?  Besides, they will want to sell me their $300 box... with no units ("farads?  What's that?").   2. The capacitors stay connected all the time.  There are discussions on the web about disconnecting your PF correction "to save money."  I have not figured that one out yet.

Comment: I did all these calcs with a colleague years ago for a wind turbine which went from 0 to 70kW... When we finally contacted the company that made our solution the tech who sized the unit said we had done a good job - took us 4 hours and him 5 minutes. If your time is that cheap then do as you wish but a reactive unit that switches in and out the right amount every second is much better in terms of money that all or nothing. However you choose. Oh and $300 must be for an empty box...

Comment: @SolarMike This is a case of "blast from the past." I knew how to solve these problems no more than... _many_... years ago and I thought I'd see if I could work it out again.  I was able to buy the (functional) welder for less than scrap prices to play at sticking some metal together.  While I am playing, I will play at figuring out go-withs, including the PF caps.

Comment: @SolarMike I read your comment again and you said "a company that makes PF correction..."  Checking out companies that make them for power lines, etc. did not occur to me.  I have not found any solid answers yet but that was a good idea.  Thanks.